# unable to load grunt-contrib module

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am using yeoman for my development workflow. I have installed grunt-contrib in my project folder, and added the loadnpm tasks in my gruntfile.js

However when I start my yeoman server, it keeps giving me the error that local npm module grunt-contrib not found.

I have even tried giving the absolute path to the module, to no avail. Below is the absolute path, is anything wrong with it ?

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('/home/murtaza/workspace/yeoman/angular/node_modules/grunt-contrib');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it running using another plugin grunt-jade. The below blog got me going -
http://www.thedjpetersen.com/blog/supercharging_yeoman/

Answer (score 2):

Without the full grunt file, it is difficult to answer completely. But in my opinion there are three possible causes:

1) loadNpmTasks should have 'grunt-contrib':

```
loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');
```

2) You need to add grunt-contrib to package.json

3) You need to run 'npm install' from your project root.